# Solve $x^2-2\sqrt{x}+1=0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ without using numerical methods?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, roots

How do I solve this equation:
$$x^2-2\sqrt{x}+1=0$$ 
in $\mathbb{R}$ without using numerical methods?

**Note**: I have used variable change by letting $y=\sqrt{x}$ I got this equation:$(y-1)(y^3+y^2+y-1)=0$, at this step I'm not able to complete the solution, and I do not want to use "Cardan" method.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: and after  what you can do ?

Comment: Actually, that cubic polynomial is a strictly increasing graph. It only has one root. But by the rational zero theorem, no rational candidates work, so you will have to go into numerical methods

Comment: even if you don't want to use Cardano's formulas you should be aware of them using: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E2-2%E2%88%9Ax+%2B1%3D%3D0

Comment: True, I did not consider Cardano either, because it was tagged as a precalculus problem :)

Comment: Cardano's formulas are precalculus by now xD

Comment: if you choose a substitution like $x=u^2$, you get $x=u^4-2u+1=0$ and $x=u^4+2u+1=0$, leading to x=1.

Comment: @EmmadKareem: OP knows that and has already factored out the $u-1$ term (except that it is called $y-1$ by OP).  The question is, what to do with the remaining cubic $y^3+y^2+y-1 = 0$.  I don't think there's anything to do other than Cardano or numerical.

Comment: @BrianTung, thx for the comment, the substitution he has choosen is the reason he ended up with 3rd degree equation. Maybe the question did not have to include the 2nd degree equation at all if all he wants to solve is the 3rd degree equation.

Comment: @EmmadKareem: OP doesn't have a second-degree equation.  $x^2-2\sqrt{x}+1 = 0$ is not a second-degree equation (not a polynomial, anyway).  My point is that I don't see anything in your comment that isn't already in OP's question.

Comment: Cardan was 15th century, 2 centuries befoe calculus

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you can do much with this except with Cardano or numerical methods.  The real root is given by

$$
y = \frac{\sqrt[3]{17+3\sqrt{33}}-1}{3}-\frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{17+3\sqrt{33}}}
  \doteq 0.54369
$$

Other than that's a lot of threes, I don't see any obvious trick.  But maybe someone will surprise us.